# MySQL- insert one table into another table in a different database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got a production(prod.products) and a development(dev.products) database. I now need to insert the table ('prod.batch-numbers') from the production database into the ('dev.batch-numbers') table within the development database as this one is not up to date. Both tables have the same layout. Any suggestions on how to do this? Quite new to MySQL so any help is appreciated!

Comment: first suggestion, perhaps its better to not have production and development in the same environment. second, do an export / import in whatever tool you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `dev`.`batch-numbersz` SELECT * FROM `prod`.`batch-numbers`;
```

Note: for this to work, you'll need to run the query from a user with proper rights on both databases.

Or simpler if you only need it done once: do an export of the production table and import it in the development database.
Most database tools support both export of tables and import of files.